# Check does device already open in Linux?

Tags: c, linux

I can [open](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) device:

```
int fileDiscription1 = open("/dev/video0", O_RDWR);
```

In another place of my code I can do it again and get another fileDescription2 for the same device... I want prevent this mistake. Does Linux standard library contains function like *lsof "/dev/video0"* or *bool IsOpen(int FileDescription)*?

Comment: If you only want to open a specific device once, I think it's up to your program to keep track of the status of the device and if it has been opened or not already.

Comment: No. A workaround would be to check `/proc` subdirectory associated with application's own PID but that's probably not what you want.